# First time using Ubuntu, or linux. How do I connect to wifi?

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have a fresh install of ubuntu server 20.4, and no experience with linux. I've been following a tutorial from Chris's Basement on youtube to get a print server running, but I'm stuck because I don't have a way to connect via ethernet. The laptop has wifi, but when I try to follow steps in other guides I either get stuck or confused.

What I've done so far is identified my wireless card with 'ls /sys/class/net' but then I get stuck on the next step. When I enter 'ls /ect/netplan/' I get No such file or directory exists. So I entered 'sudo apt install netplan.io' and get netplan.io is already the newest version (0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2)

So I'm confused, do I have netplan? Is this even how I should be connecting to wifi? Any guidance would be appreciated, I'm so lost.

Comment: See the Search box at the top of each AskUbuntu page? Enter your wireless hardware model number in that box. Examples: "RTL8825" or "BCM2214a"

Comment: The obvious error in your question is a misspelling of /etc/ (which would of course result in the error you post).  *that isn't where I'd look for details though; you've provided no details as to your hardware*

Comment: it's not ect as in ectera? What is etc? But yeah, I found my yaml file thanks

Comment: @ThatGuy etc refers to the word etcetera, which is put after lists to represent that it is not complete. For example: bacon, eggs, cheese, etc.